# Why I couldn't inject default index.js file to the root html?

Tags: reactjs

I am newbie to react js. After I setup the project folder to start coding I deleted the src folder and recreated it. Inside the src I created index.js and import all react libraries. But I am not seeing my hello world rendered on the localhost:3000 page. What could be the reason?

Comment: What does your `index.html` code look like?

Comment: To get help from other users you will have to share your code what you have added (the changes you have done after deleting the src folder)

Comment: I made no change on the index.html code. But my index.js code is the following

   ` import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(<div>hello React</div>,document.getElementById('root'));`

Comment: Did you see your bundle js file gets injected to your html file yet?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with specifying relative path to your `index.js` and `App.js`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class Index extends Component {
render(){
return(
<div><h1>hello world</h1></div>
)
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Could you explain what this is or how it solves the problem OP is having?

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete your project folder
2. You then reinitiate `npx create-react-app appname` since you've not codded any logic yet, you've probably deleted a needed dependency file

When cleaning the hello world, don't delete the whole src folder. Just delete the files in the src folder except for the app.js and index.js